# SSIS chicken-and-egg situation with Access MDB file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've developed an SSIS 2012 package that:

1) runs an executable to create an Access MDB file (based on data extracted from a PDF)

2) uses a data flow to load a table in the MDB file to a SQL Server table.

The problem I'm running into is, the first time the job is run, the MDB file doesn't exist because the executable that creates it hasn't run yet.  So if I try to run the package, it can't validate the Access database and it fails.

I thought maybe if I set the "Delay Validation" property on the Access data source it might help, but no dice.

The only way around this I've found is to place an empty copy of the MDB file on the server.  Then the package validates OK and proceeds to overwrite the MDB with a fresh copy.

This works but seems cheezy. There must be a better way.

Comment: What if you set Delay Validation on the package as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Connection Manager has DelayValidation set to true, however the executables in the package are still going to try and validate and fail. In the properties for the Package, change the `DelayValidation` property to `True`.